# How to organize or extract info from a QByteArray

Tags: c++, qt, qbytearray

I have a programm that recieves a full block in a single QByteArray. This block is "divided" with 'carriage returns' followed by 'end lines' (`\r\n`). In the middle of all this junk I have a date. Most specifically in the third line (between the second and the third `\r\n`).

Every time I try to extract this date from the ByteArray I end up with some random junk. How to be more precise with the QByteArray?

What is the best way of extracting this date without altering my ByteArray? Take in consideration that I don't know the date and it can even be in the wrong format.

Just for understanding purposes, here is an example of my ByteArray:

> RandomName=name\r\nRandomID=ID\r\nRandomDate=**date**\r\nRandomTime=time\r\nRandomWhatever=whatever(...)

EDIT:

Sorry for bad english.

Let's say I have the following text sent to me:

> ProgName = Marcus
>   ProgID = 180
>   ProgDate = 15.01.16
>   ProgTime = 13:39
>   (More info)......

However, none of this information is useful to me... except the Date. Everything was stored in a single QByteArray (Let's call it 'ba'). So this is my ba:

> ProgName(space)=(space)Marcus\r\nProgID(space)=(space)180\r\nProgDate(space)=(space)15.01.16\r\nProgTime(space)=(space)13:39\r\n (keeps going)

My problem is: Storing "15.01.16" (the "ProgDate") in a QString without altering or destroying ba.

Comment: How are you converting the bytes back to chars? It seems like all you'd need to do is scan the QByteArray for the index of the second "\r\n", get the index of the '=' char, then copy every char up to the next "\r\n" char pair...

Comment: You are describing everything as "random junk". Your input is random junk, your output is random junk, stuff in the middle is random junk. Edit your question to show what you have tried, show the result you are getting, and show the result which you expect.

Comment: @user2647513 Yeah, i tried doing that way but ended up getting the wrong part of the ByteArray. Most likely was my own bad use of the function

Comment: @BarmakShemirani I am sorry. I wil try to be a little more clear when I edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a variety of ways, but try one of the following solutions.

1) using split()

```
foreach (auto subByte, yourByteArray.replace("\r\n", "\n").split('\n')) {
    qDebug() << subByte;
    foreach (auto val, subByte.split('=')) {
        qDebug() << val;
    }
}
```

2) using QRegularExpression/QRegularExpressionMatchIterator, making all pair(key, value)

```
QRegularExpression  re("(\\w+)=(\\w+)");
QRegularExpressionMatchIterator i = re.globalMatch(yourByteArray);

while (i.hasNext()) {
    QRegularExpressionMatch match = i.next();
    qDebug() << match.captured(0)<< match.captured(1) << match.captured(2);
}
```

3) using QRegularExpression/QRegularExpressionMatch

```
QRegularExpression  re("(RandomDate)=(\\w+)");
QRegularExpressionMatch match = re.match(yourByteArray);

if (match.hasMatch())
    qDebug() << match.captured(0)<< match.captured(1) << match.captured(2);
```

Comment: Hum, I liked the first option but mostly because it is easier to understand. I will give it a shot and report back. Thanks